# Maximum number of lines for a Wrap TextBlock

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-8, uwp-xaml, textblock

I have a `TextBlock` with the following setting:

```
TextWrapping="Wrap"
```

Can I determine the maximum number of lines?

for example consider the following string `TextBlock.Text`:

```
This is a very good horse under the blackboard!!
```

It currently has been shows like this:

```
This is a very 
good horse under 
the blackboard!!
```

I need that to become something like:

```
This is a very 
good horse ...
```

any solution?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

## Update (for UWP)

In UWP Apps you don't need this and can use the TextBlock property `MaxLines` (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.maxlines))

---

## Original Answer:

If you have a specific `LineHeight` you can calculate the **maximum height** for the TextBlock.

#### Example:

*TextBlock with maximum 3 lines*

```
<TextBlock 
  Width="300"
  TextWrapping="Wrap" 
  TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
  FontSize="24" 
  LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
  LineHeight="28"
  MaxHeight="84">YOUR TEXT</TextBlock>
```

This is all that you need to get your requirement working.

#### How to do this dynamically?

Just create a new control in C#/VB.NET that extends `TextBlock` and give it a new `DependencyProperty` *int MaxLines*.

Then override the `OnApplyTemplate()` method and set the `MaxHeight` based on the `LineHeight` * `MaxLines`.

That's just a basic explanation on how you could solve this problem!

Answer (score 7):

Based tobi.at's and gt's answer I have created this `MaxLines` behaviour. Crucially it doesn't depend upon setting the `LineHeight` property by calculating the line height from the font. You still need to set `TextWrapping` and `TextTrimming` for it the `TextBox` to be render as you would like.

```
<TextBlock behaviours:NumLinesBehaviour.MaxLines="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="Some text here"/>
```

There in also a `MinLines` behaviour which can be different or set to the same number as the `MaxLines` behaviour to set the number of lines.

```
public class NumLinesBehaviour : Behavior<TextBlock>
{
    TextBlock textBlock => AssociatedObject;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxLinesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "MaxLines",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(NumLinesBehaviour),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(int), OnMaxLinesPropertyChangedCallback));

    public static void SetMaxLines(DependencyObject element, int value)
    {
        element.SetValue(MaxLinesProperty, value);
    }

    public static int GetMaxLines(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (int)element.GetValue(MaxLinesProperty);
    }

    private static void OnMaxLinesPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock element = d as TextBlock;
        element.MaxHeight = getLineHeight(element) * GetMaxLines(element);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinLinesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "MinLines",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(NumLinesBehaviour),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(int), OnMinLinesPropertyChangedCallback));

    public static void SetMinLines(DependencyObject element, int value)
    {
        element.SetValue(MinLinesProperty, value);
    }

    public static int GetMinLines(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (int)element.GetValue(MinLinesProperty);
    }

    private static void OnMinLinesPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock element = d as TextBlock;
        element.MinHeight = getLineHeight(element) * GetMinLines(element);
    }

    private static double getLineHeight(TextBlock textBlock)
    {
        double lineHeight = textBlock.LineHeight;
        if (double.IsNaN(lineHeight))
            lineHeight = Math.Ceiling(textBlock.FontSize * textBlock.FontFamily.LineSpacing);
        return lineHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: After removing the unnecessary stuff, like ": Behavior<TextBlock>" and the following lines of code, that obviously derived from the Behavior base class, it worked like a charm. So only use a static class, with the dependencyProperties.

Answer (score 6):

If you have `Height`, `TextWrapping`, and `TextTrimming` all set, it will behave exactly like you want:

```
<TextBlock Height="60" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Thin"
    TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
```

The above code will wrap up to two lines, then use `CharacterEllipsis` beyond that point.

Answer (score 2):

you need `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` setting in your `TextBlock`

Comment: Thanks, but that only works if the text reaches the end of the `TextBlock` which might be 2 lines or more. I want `TextBlock` to trim the text after e.g. exactly 2 lines.

Comment: @MBZ For that you need to write custom converter which goes through your `TextBlock` text and inserts ellipses where needed.

Comment: If you can set the height of the textblock, trimming and wrapping set should be all that you need

Answer (score 2):

Based on @artistandsocial's answer, I created a attached property to set the maximum number of lines programatically (rather than having to overload `TextBlock` which is discouraged in WPF).

```
public class LineHeightBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxLinesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "MaxLines",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(LineHeightBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(int), OnMaxLinesPropertyChangedCallback));

    public static void SetMaxLines(TextBlock element, int value) => element.SetValue(MaxLinesProperty, value);

    public static int GetMaxLines(TextBlock element) =>(int)element.GetValue(MaxLinesProperty);

    private static void OnMaxLinesPropertyChangedCallback(
        DependencyObject d, 
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is TextBlock textBlock)
        {
            if (textBlock.IsLoaded)
            {
               SetLineHeight();
            }
            else
            {
                textBlock.Loaded += OnLoaded;

                void OnLoaded(object _, RoutedEventArgs __)
                {
                    textBlock.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
                    SetLineHeight();
                }
            }

            void SetLineHeight()
            {
                double lineHeight =
                   double.IsNaN(textBlock.LineHeight)
                        ? textBlock.FontFamily.LineSpacing * textBlock.FontSize
                        : textBlock.LineHeight;
                textBlock.MaxHeight = Math.Ceiling(lineHeight * GetMaxLines(textBlock));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By default, the `LineHeight` is set to `double.NaN`, so this value must first be set manually, otherwise a height is calculated from the `FontFamily` and `FontSize` of the `TextBlock`.

The attached property `MaxLines` and other relevant properties can then be set in a `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
    <Setter Property="TextTrimming"
            Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping"
            Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="LineHeight"
            Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy"
            Value="BlockLineHeight" />
    <Setter Property="behaviors:LineHeightBehavior.MaxLines"
            Value="2" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody developing UWP or WinRT Applications, `TextBlock` has a [`MaxLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBlock_MaxLines) property you can set.

Answer (score -4):

I doubt that is configurable, Wrapping is based on a number of factors such as font-size/kerning, available width of the textblock (horizontalalignment=stretch can make a big difference), parent's panel type (scrollviewer/stackpanel/grid) etc.

If you want the text to flow to the next line explicitly you should use "Run" blocks instead and then use wrapping of type ellipses for that run block.

Comment: See @kindasimple's comment below, that will give you what you want.

Comment: Why is this chosen as the answer?